# Dynamically add TableRow to above of TableLayout

Tags: android, view, addition, tablelayout, tablerow

I want to dynamically add `TableRow` to above of `TableLayout`. I use blow code:

In my activity:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)ChatActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tblChats);
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            TableRow row = (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(ChatActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.chat_row, null);
            ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.attrib_name)).setText("A");
            ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.attrib_value)).setText(i + "");
            table.addView(row);
        }
        table.requestLayout();
```

chat_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/attrib_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/attrib_value"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="normal"/>

</TableRow>
```

As you know these codes adds `TableRow` in the bottom of the `TableLayout`.

Is there any way to add it to the above of `TableLayout`?

Comment: Yes I wanna do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Android Team's answer I realized I must change this line:

```
table.addView(row);
```

to this:

```
table.addView(row, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

yes you can add row as runtime in table layout.
use below code like chart.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<TableLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tblChats"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">  </TableLayout>
```

and make activity like below ..

```
public class ChartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chart_layout);
        TableLayout table = findViewById(R.id.tblChats);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(lp);
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText("Name" + " " + i);
            EditText editText = new EditText(this);
            row.addView(textView);
            table.addView(row, i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So I must use it:
table.addView(row, 0);
Thank you it works.